# how to make flexible div with css or typeciprt with angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

```css
.resizable_div {
  border:1px solid red;
  white-space:nowrap; 
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px; 
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  /*margin:50px auto;*/
  padding:5px;
  resize:horizontal;
  cursor:col-resize;
  min-width:50px;
  max-width:150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="resizable_div">This is an example</div>
```

What I want to do here is to pull from the left side and make a resizeable div, that is, I want to enlarge or reduce it by holding it from the left side.
(when i expand it should expand to the left and when i collapse it should contract to the right)

Comment: Kindly update the question and provide us the issue you are facing as well as the things you have tried.

Comment: As you can see in snipedd, my resizable div only gets longer and shorter to the right. I want the same action to be on the left side.
 @Eagnir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your attention guys, this is how I found the solution

```
   resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    direction: rtl;
    float: right;
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer, it would surely help the next person.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the item itself resizable you will need to change it using the same method as normal Javascript. One specific tip for Angular is that you could use an [ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) to access the item and do it in the component code or attach an angular [event binding](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding) to the div itself for the mouse events you wish to target.

Something like this could be a start:

```
<div (click)="resizeItem()">Resize Me</div>
```

and in your angular component file

```
function resizeItem(){
  // width changes either by updating a bound variable or attaching to the event target 
}
```

You can also read more about [event binding concepts](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding-concepts).

And if this is all still complicated, You might want to start by going through the [Angular start guide](https://angular.io/start).